# How could I solve complement in this exercise of Bayes

Tags: probability-theory, bayes-theorem

I have the following problem:

We suppose I have a company which builds houses. And I have a contract. I need to meet deadlines in end July, but that depends if I receive materials in middle July.

According to my experience, the probability of receiving materials middle of July are $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\pmb{if}$ I receive materials at time ( middle July), probability of meeting deadlines are $\frac{3}{4}$

So my question is : If I meet deadlines end of July , what would be probability that the cause were because I NOT received material at time (midde July).

If I model the problem I would have:

A = meets deadlines end July. So A = $\frac{3}{4}$

B= receive materials middle July. So B = $\frac{2}{3}$

I want to use a approach of Bayes theorem for this problem so:

Fist I calculate the probability that A $\pmb{and}$ B are met:

$P(A\bigcap B)= P(A\mid B)P(B)$

$P(A\bigcap B)= \frac{3}{4} * \frac{2}{3}$

$P(A\bigcap B)= \frac{1}{2}$

If I want to calculate Bayes' theorem to see probability that I finish house end of July but NOT receive materials at time I do :

$$P(B\mid A) =\frac{P(A\mid B)P(B)}{P(A\mid |B)P(B) + P(A\mid B^c)P(B^c)}$$

Problem is that I can't see $P(A\mid B^c)$ for calculate total probability.

Is it the same that $3/4$? but that doesn't make sense to me?

Comment: I agree with you.  I don't think here's enough information to solve this problem, unless we're supposed to assume that if you don't receive the materials by the middle of July, you certainly cannot complete the contract, and that seems like a bit of a stretch to me.

Comment: The only path to success we are told about is "get the materials in time and then finish the project on time".  If there is some other path to success, we'd need information about it.

Comment: @saulspatz this problem was originally about conditional probability. But I wanted go beyond of that. That's why I wanted to calculate probability of causes. But It seems that obligatorilly we need two conditions for bayes . First one conditional probability of B , and second one conditional probabilitty of complement of B.